# scrollToRow doesn't scroll accurately

Tags: swift, uitableview

In the app I'm working on I have a Tab Bar Controller with four screens.
Within each tabbed area is a separate Navigation Controller stack for the screens relating to that part of the app.
One of these is the Settings section and here I want the user to be able to change their location, if necessary.  Just as with the Settings section on the iPhone.

Therefore, I have the list of countries - grouped in sections based on their initial letters - showing in a `UITableView`.  A default country is chosen and, just as with the iPhone Settings, I'd like the `UITableView` to show that country as the top line when it's first presented.

I currently have the `scrollToRow` placed in the `viewDidLoad` as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Code to sort countries into sections and to find the correct initial country, index of which is store in selectedIndex

    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: selectedIndex ?? IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)
}
```

Now, if the initial country is near the top of the list, everything works without a problem. But if it's near the bottom, say the United Kingdom, it doesn't get scrolled to the top, merely near the top - despite being able to scroll further.  It is almost as if it forgets that the Tab Bar is present and won't scroll any higher.  Manually, of course, it has no problem scrolling higher. (I'm not sure how to include an image with this post, hence the description.)

I had another problem with scrollToRow a few months ago and solved it by inserting the `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` just before the call to `scrollToRow`, hence it's inclusion here.  But it doesn't work here.

I have tried placing the call to `scrollToRow` in `viewDidAppear`, as was recommended in one article I read, but then the table is presented without the country visible before 'jumping' to the correct row.  I'd like it to be there when the screen opens.

Anybody with any ideas?  Thanks.

(I'm using Xcode 11.3 for an iOS 11.0 environment.)

Comment: Have you tried switching `.top` to `.bottom`?

Comment: @Wyetro - just tried that and the selected row isn't visible at all.  So, the `scrollToRow` isn't taking into account the Tab Bar at all.  Deals with it when manually scrolling, but not when forcing the scroll programmatically.  How can I get around this?

Comment: Blocking the TabBar doesn't seem to make any difference either.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a check before scrollToRow

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
        
     // Code to sort countries into sections and to find the correct initial country, index of which is store in selectedIndex
        
    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

    if tableView.numberOfSections >= selectedIndex.section
      ,tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: selectedIndex.section) >= selectedIndex.row {
           self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: selectedIndex, at: .top, animated: false)
    }
}
```